Manually run of API do not starting with SSL
I have suddenly updated my .net core web api to .NET 8. For efficiency reason I start it always the .exe file to develop my other applications.
In .Net 6 it started always with and without ssl, see the output in the console:

Since I updated to .NET 8, it only starts without ssl. I changed nothing else than the framework version. Output looks like this:

But if I debug the application in Rider, it also starts with ssl (what I think is correct).
My launch.json looks like this:
"MyApp.Api": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": false,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }

Do I have to change anything after the .NET update to execute the API with ssl? Is there any change in .NET which causes this?

launchSettings.json is only used when run from VS. When run from console, you need to add the Kestrel section to your appsettings.json as per this.

Actually in .NET 6 it wasn't in my case, so I thought I don't have to do this. But then I will add it.
